# How to solve 'oc is not recognized as an internal or external command' problem?

Tags: openshift, minishift

I have installed Minishift, started it successfully but now I am not able to use oc command. Please help. Below is the screenshot.

[image: oc command not found]

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem:-

1. Get path of oc command:- # minishift oc-env
2. Set the path using SET PATH command.

Please see below screenshot for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1 download oc.exe https://developers.redhat.com/openshift/command-line-tools

2 navigate to environment variables -> system variables -> new

3 add here: /path/to/the/oc.exe